# How can I justify my eagerness to be trained in mathematics to my employer?

Tags: education, training

Our office has a budget for training. But on one condition: It should improve/help or at least be useful to the current work we do on our team (VBA Development using Access/Excel).

I am eager to learn mathematics. I know without the word 'Mathematics' there is no such word called 'Engineering' (all sort of). The problem is, how do I justify my request for training? They are asking for a business case where it will prove to be useful. What to do?

Comment: "They are asking for a business case where it will prove to be useful."  That's your answer right there.

Comment: If you can't say why it will be valuable to your employer, you do have the option of paying for it yourself. If it isn't worth that much to you, and you can't show that it's worth that much to them,  consider self-study or free online courses.

Comment: What do you mean by "mathematics"? That's such a broad term that it could mean anything.  And I don't think mathematics is something that can be "trained" in 1-2 weeks.

Comment: You don't happen do work in Germany, do you? Then you could take *"Bildungsurlaub"* (educational leave) which is not liked by some companies, but mandated by law. You get up to 5 days per year paid leave to participate in educational seminars which do not necessarily need to apply to your profession, but you will have to pay for the training yourself.

Comment: Good luck with your training. I would probably attempt to learn some newer tech. I didn't know they were still doing vba with access.

Answer (score 6):

Unless it is a skill that you need to perform your role, then it's highly unlikely that you will be able to get your employer to pay for it.

In your question you state "You want to learn mathematics".  Mathematics is a very broad field.  The questions you need to ask yourself, and how to frame it as a business case would include:

- What strand within mathematics am I interested in?
- How does this apply to my job and the work I do?
- If I learned this skill, would it make me better at my job?
- Would this add value to your employer?  How much?

If you are unable to bring these together into a business case, then your employer has no real reason to spend this money.  However, you can certainly undertake study in your own time in whatever strand takes your interest!